# Translation: “世界上，治疗心脏病最好的方式就是不要开刀。”

Tags: translation

Looking for another retrograde translation.

Here's the excerpt:

> 美国有一个心脏病之父，他一生开过，开胸开一万多人。他，美国的心脏科医生都知道，尊称他为心脏病之父。他死掉以后呢，在他的墓碑上面，刻了......了一句话在上面：“世界上，治疗心脏病最好的方式就是不要开刀。”

This obviously comes from English.

- What's the original English quote of: `“世界上，治疗心脏病最好的方式就是不要开刀。”`?

Comment: "I would like to think that I've left the world of cardiovascular surgery
better than when I found it. That would be a suitable epitaph." — C. Walton Lillehei, 1995.

Comment: @Stan That's an answer.

Comment: Hmm, it would be better to ask this question in the chat room.

Comment: This Chinese version is clearly a made up one. Many Chinese quotes' translators love to adjust/make up things for their own believes. This is very bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The epitaph is *probably*

> "I would like to think that I've left the world of cardiovascular surgery better than when I found it. That would be a suitable epitaph." — C. Walton Lillehei, 1995.

#### *materials*

1. [`C. Walton Lillehei, the “Father of Open Heart Surgery”`](http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/100/13/1364.full). This article proves Mr. Lillehei has the title "心脏病之父", and he is an American.
2. [*State of the Heart: The Practical Guide to Your Heart and Heart Surgery*](http://www.ctsnet.org/book/soth/front_rev.pdf). This book quotes what he said as

   [image: epitaph]
3. However I cannot find that epitaph on [his tombstone](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=6952).

   [image: Lillehei]

   So, the statement "在他的墓碑上面，刻了..." seems not true.